# Choosing loss function for lstm trained on word2vec vectors when target is a vector of same dimensions

Tags: pytorch, lstm, word2vec

I have an lstm I'm using as a sequence-generator trained on word2vec vectors. The previous implementation produced a probability distribution for all the different labels. There was one label for every word in the vocabulary. This implementation used Pytorch's CrossEntropyLoss. I now want to change this so the lstm outputs a vector that has the same dimensions as the vectors used for training. This way I could use the euclydian distance measure to match wit to nearby vectors in the vocabulary. The problem is that in order to do this, I have to use a different loss function, because CrossEntropyLoss is appropriate for classifiers and not for regression problems.

I tried changing the format of the target vector, but torch's CrossEntropyLoss function requires integer input, and I have a word vector. Having looked at a few options it seems Cosine Embedding Loss might be a good idea but I don't understand how it works and what kind of input it takes.

I have already changed my fully connected layer to output vectors of the same dimensions as the Word Embeddings used for training:

```
nn.Linear(in_features=self.cfg.lstm.lstm_num_hidden,out_features=self.cfg.lstm.embedding_dim,bias=True)
```

Any advice and examples would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation of [CosineEmbeddingLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=cosine%20embedding%20loss#torch.nn.CosineEmbeddingLoss) says:

> Creates a criterion that measures the loss given two input tensors and a Tensor label with values 1 or -1.

In your scenario, you should always provide 1 as the Tensor label.

```
batch_size, seq_len, w2v_dim = 32, 100, 200
x1 = torch.randn(batch_size, seq_len, w2v_dim)
x2 = torch.randn(batch_size, seq_len, w2v_dim)
y = torch.ones(batch_size, seq_len)
loss_fn = torch.nn.CosineEmbeddingLoss(reduction='none')
loss = loss_fn(x1.view(-1, w2v_dim), 
               x2.view(-1, w2v_dim),  
               y.view(-1))
loss = loss.view(batch_size, seq_len)
```

Here, I assume `x1` is the word embeddings, `x2` is the output of the LSTM followed by some transformation.

> Why should I always provide 1 as the Tensor label?

First, you should see the loss function.

[image]

In your scenario, the higher the cosine similarity is, the lower the loss should be. In other words, you want to maximize the cosine similarity. So, you need to provide 1 as the label.

On the other hand, if you want to minimize the cosine similarity, you need to provide -1 as the label.

Comment: I've looked at the documentation and I can't figure out what the "tensor label" is, and why I should always provide 1. Can you elaborate?

Comment: should the values of x1 and x2 be normalized by passing through softmax ???